# Chrome 107 - marks self-signed certificate Not Secure despite cert is installed

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate, https

I'm running create-react-app with self-signed HTTPS certificate locally.
The certificate is installed in User's Trusted Root CA
[image]

Despite that Chrome still marks the website as Not Secure what for example disallows hot reloads.

[image]

And without #allow-insecure-localhost flag enabled I can't even open it.
The same website is marked as Secure in Edge. Any ideas what else can I do?

Comment: Try to click anywhere on the denial page and type `thisisunsafe`. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802767/no-proceed-anyway-option-on-neterr-cert-invalid-in-chrome-on-macos))

Comment: it just allows me to open website without #allow-insecure-localhost flag enabled but what I need is to have this website marked as Secured like it would have a valid, signed by trusted CA

Comment: It seems like Chrome starting from version 99 (or 88?) doesn't accept such certificates. You may continue to use Edge or other clones. Or get a [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem the last couple of days. Very annoying! Accepting the insecurity doesn't work, indeed, since all XHR calls are still not loaded (error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`). And @harrymc : if only that were possible, but this is a certificate for localhost for web development and even [Letsencrypt points out](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/#for-local-development) that you need a self-signed certificate for that!

Comment: @PascalLindelauf: Your link also suggests that `127.0.0.1` gets a better treatment than `localhost` (if the latest Chrome still supports that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Chrome policy:
ChromeRootStoreEnabled
false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've added ChromeRootStoreEnabled with value 0 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome and it worked. Unfortunately this policy is planned to be removed https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=ChromeRootStoreEnabled
and I wonder why self-signed certificate for IIS works as Trusted without this policy change

Comment: Of course they will delete it. Because chrome will stop using the built-in certificate store!

Comment: Although this is not a final solution (and I can't seem to use it on MacOS), it *does* point to the culprit and that is the introduction of [Chrome's own Certificate Root Store](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/faq.md). Unfortunately I haven't been able to find how to best deal with (self signed) SSL certificates for my development machine. For now I reverted to using Chromium v106.

Comment: I'm in same boat as @PascalLindelauf. Chrome's FAQ's suggest to "Add a CA certificate to the platform root store", which I've done (I'm on a Mac also). The problem still persists.

Comment: Further details on Chrome 107 "enhancements" can be found here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#certVerifRem107
Question is, how can we use the new "Chrome Root Store" along with our own internal trusted store?

Comment: I've raised a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1393363

Comment: And I've implemented the suggested solution to set the chrome policy ChromeRootStoreEnabled to false and restarted browser but this has not changed anything.
I'll switch to Firefox until Google sorts this mess out.

Comment: another bug someone else logged: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1380776&q=chrome%20107%20self%20signed%20certificates&can=2

Comment: This has been removed in Crhome 113. How can I achieve this with new Chrome versions?

Answer (score 2):

If your SSL connection is to localhost, you can use "Allow insecure localhost" workaround by going to `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: confirming that this works for a quick and dirty solution for local development (Chrome Version 122.0.6261.57 (Official Build) (64-bit))